# pager without javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, seo

how to use  Pager(GridView or ListView)  with html link.
is that right that this code is not SEO friendly?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions.

First:
You can implement a pager by using post-backs. Basically you will invoke a server call at each click of a link. And the server would reply with a new page of the dataset. But the asp.net controls submit the form using javascript. It looks like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javscript:document.forms[0].submit();">link text</a>
```

So to not use the javascript at all, you could use a HTTP GET only method. This is just one way to do it.

So what you want generated is something that, it will pass to your server a page value using a query string parameter named 'page'.

You can handle that in your aspx page any way you see fit. But it needs to generate some thing like that.

```
<a href="./somepage.aspx?page=2">page 2</a>
```

In the page load of somepage.aspx you handle it.

```
protected void page_load(EventArgs e){
    // check if the page parameter is set in the query string
    if(Request.QueryString["page"] != null){

        // page is the value of the requested page
        var page = Request.QueryString["page"];
    }
    // bind you data to the control.
}
```

Then when binding the data to your GridView or ListView you filter the data based on the page requested.

Answer (score 1):

@pre has a good answer for your first question.

Regarding your second about SEO and JavaScript:

JavaScript has to be used correctly.  In other words, the html has to have the links and all of the pieces necessary to be read by a spider.  If nav elements are injected via JavaScript then you can be assured that a spider will not see them.

You can certainly use JavaScript to change the styling, reposition the pager area or add other attributes but the base anchor tags with the appropriate href attributes have to be present.